# Mercurial hg Subrepository issue - "abort: unknown revision'

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

Note: I asked this yesterday over at [kiln.stackexchange.com](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/825/hg-subrepository-problem-abort-unknown-revision/840#840), but haven't gotten an answer, and it's holding up my work. So I figured I'd give it a shot here.

My main mercurial repository has a bunch of subrepositories in it. During initial setup, I made a mistake in my `.hgsub`. Namely, I pointed two subrepositories to the same directory.

What I should have had:

```
sites/1=sites/1
sites/2=sites/2
sites/3=sites/3
```

What I actually had:

```
sites/1=sites/1
sites/2=sites/2
sites/2=sites/3
```

Stupid copy/paste error. I committed the incorrect `.hgsub`, not realizing my error. A few revisions later, while adding a some new subrespositories to `.hgsub`, I noticed the mistake and fixed it inside `.hgsub`. I committed and kept rolling along. I've committed a reasonable amount of work that I'd prefer not to redo since I 'fixed' the mistake in `.hgsub`.

Now we come to the actual problem: I've made some changes inside the subrepository `sites/3`, and when I try to commit the main repository, I get the following error:

`abort: unknown revision 'LongGUIDLookingString'`

I found [this discussion](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1771), which seems to address the same problem I'm having, but I can't quite work out how bos fixed it. What do I need to do in order to fix this?

Relevant section of `.hgsubstate`:

```
7d1e430ac5f12e00cb5bebcdf693e72db2c45732 sites/1
6eea936a5b7cfff6169f59d0dc1c8c4eb5f8412d sites/2
e2b83b301997de8add1b659d82a7ab8201bda653 sites/3
```

Comment: Is there a + at the end of the string?

Comment: No plus. Here's the actual string: 'e2b83b301997de8add1b659d82a7ab8201bda653'.

Comment: @tonfa: what if it does have the + at the end? (it does for me but being ungooglable I don't know where to go from here).

Comment: @romkyns the + at the end means the subrepo is dirty (aka modified), I don't think such hashes are supposed to end up in .hgsubstate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd guess the .hgsubstate file now contains a hashid (which is what your LongGUIDLookingString is) from repo3 in the repo2 entry.

Try editing .hgsubstate to point to a correct/present hashid for each repo.

If that doesn't work, please paste i your .hgsubstate file so we can see how it can be tweaked.

Comment: Are you talking about the changeset hashid? The changeset hash IDs of the subrepos don't look anything like the hashes in `.hgsubstate`. Or is there another hashid associated with the `sites/3` subrepository (other than inside `.hgsubstate`)? I've added the relevant section of `.hgsubstate` to the original question.

Comment: Ok, I see now that mercurial usually shows a shortened version of each changeset id. `hg --debug tags` gets the longer version.

I executed that on `sites/3`, pasted the tip changeset id into `.hgsubstate` on the `sites/3` line, and I'm now able to commit again. Looks to be cleaned up now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No prob.  I should've mentioned the long-form (complete) hashids.  You can get them as {node} in the template language: hg log --template '{node}'  with '{node|short}' getting you the ones you're used to seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggle committing changes to `.hgsubstate`, it appears that:

- `hg commit -i` is not working while
- `hg commit -m` does.